# How can I give a set of HTML attributes a 'class'-like name?

Tags: html

I have this SVG image that I will be using multiple times in my code:

`<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1408 960v-128q0-26-19-45t-45-19h-320v-320q0-26-19-45t-45-19h-128q-26 0-45 19t-19 45v320h-320q-26 0-45 19t-19 45v128q0 26 19 45t45 19h320v320q0 26 19 45t45 19h128q26 0 45-19t19-45v-320h320q26 0 45-19t19-45zm256-544v960q0 119-84.5 203.5t-203.5 84.5h-960q-119 0-203.5-84.5t-84.5-203.5v-960q0-119 84.5-203.5t203.5-84.5h960q119 0 203.5 84.5t84.5 203.5z"/></svg>`

How can I give it a 'class' so I can use it like `<svg class="icon_svg><path class="icon_path" /></svg>`.

In CSS I can give a set of styles a class name, how can I do this with HTML attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML has no such feature. CSS has no such feature.

The usual technique for reusing chunks of markup is to select a template engine and apply it with a programming language.

This could be done with client side JavaScript, but it is more usual and reliable to use either a server side language or a preprocessing language (which would generate static files which you would publish to your webserver at deployment time).

Lately I've been using [Nunjunks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) ([with Gulp](https://iainhouston.com/blog/gulp-workflow-for-static-website-no-blog.html)), but other options include [TT](http://template-toolkit.org/), [Assemble](http://assemble.io/), and even a simple [PHP include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

---

For SVG specifically you can [use `<defs>` and `<use>`](http://vanseodesign.com/web-design/svg-definition-reuse/):

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">  
   <defs>
      <path id="myPath" d="M1408 960v-128q0-26-19-45t-45-19h-320v-320q0-26-19-45t-45-19h-128q-26 0-45 19t-19 45v320h-320q-26 0-45 19t-19 45v128q0 26 19 45t45 19h320v320q0 26 19 45t45 19h128q26 0 45-19t19-45v-320h320q26 0 45-19t19-45zm256-544v960q0 119-84.5 203.5t-203.5 84.5h-960q-119 0-203.5-84.5t-84.5-203.5v-960q0-119 84.5-203.5t203.5-84.5h960q119 0 203.5 84.5t84.5 203.5z"/>
  </defs>
</svg>

<h1>Show the content</h1>

<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">  
  <use  xlink:href="#myPath">
</svg>

<p>Hello, world</p>

<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">  
  <use  xlink:href="#myPath">
</svg>

<p>Hello, world</p>

<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">  
  <use  xlink:href="#myPath">
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.icon_svg {width: 10px; height: 10px; background: url(img.svg) no-repeat 0 0 / 10px 10px;}
```

and in html

```
<i class="icon_svg"></i>
```

Comment: But he wants to do this with `path`.